# Solving $dX_{t} = \mu X_{t} dt + \sigma dW_{t}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, sde

I want to solve the following SDE:

$$ dX_{t} = \mu X_{t} dt + \sigma dW_{t} \quad X_{0} = x_{0}$$

Integrating, I get:

$$ X_{t}  - x_{0}= \mu \int_{0}^{t} X_{s} ds + \sigma \int_{0}^{T} dW_{t} $$
$$ X_{t}  = x_{0} + \mu \int_{0}^{t} X_{s} ds + \sigma [W_{t} - W_{0}] $$
$$ X_{t}  = x_{0} + \mu \int_{0}^{t} X_{s} ds + \sigma W_{t} $$

This is where I get stuck -- How do I proceed?

---

I know that the solution to:

$$ dX_{t} = \mu X_{t} dt + \sigma X{t} dW_{t} \quad X_{0} = x_{0}$$

Is given by:

$$ X_{t} = X_{0}e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2})t} + \sigma W_{t}$$

This is given by the fundamental matrix solution. (Though honestly I am not sure how this is derived, so I can't specialize it to my case).

---

Sorry for such a basic question. I am trying to learn this from resources on the web. So if anyone could recommend a good book dealing with how to actually solve SDEs, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Consider $d\big(e^{-\mu t} X_t \big)$.

Comment: Okay so then: $ d(e^{\mu t} X_{t})$ = $X_{t} d(e^{\mu t}) + e^{\mu t} dX_{t} = \mu X_{t} e^{\mu t} dt + e^{\mu t} dX_{t}$. Solving this for $X_{t}$ I get: $X_{t} = \sigma \frac{dW}{dt}$. That doesn't seem right. Or is it? I am not sure.

Comment: there is a minus sign

Comment: @Gordon. In this case I get: $d(e^{- \mu t} X_{t})= 0$. What am I doing wrong? Could you please explain how to solve this for an idiot like me? And why do you want to consider that function anyway?  I am an engineer trying to learn SDEs from ground up because I realized I could use them to specify prediction models in Kalman filters. However I have no idea what I am doing -- just piecing it together piece by piece.

Comment: @Gordon could you use something other than $e^{-\mu t}$ here?

Comment: To eliminate the term $\mu X_t dt$, an integrating factor of the form $e^{-\mu t}$ is the only choice.

Comment: After you first integrate your SDE, you have $$\sigma \int_{0}^{T} dW_{t} $$. Should it not be $$\sigma \int_{0}^{t} dW_{t} $$ instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you need to read some books such as [Stochastic Differential Equations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540047581). For such type of equations, you need to use something called integrating factor such as the function $e^{-\mu t}$ here. Note that
\begin{align*}
d\big(e^{-\mu t} X_t \big) &= X_t d\big(e^{-\mu t}\big) + e^{-\mu t} dX_t\\
&=-\mu e^{-\mu t} X_t dt + e^{-\mu t} (\mu X_t dt + \sigma dW_t)\\
&=\sigma e^{-\mu t} dW_t.
\end{align*}
Then, for $t > s \ge 0$,
\begin{align*}
e^{-\mu t} X_t = e^{-\mu s} X_s+ \int_s^t \sigma e^{-\mu v} dW_v.
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
X_t &= X_s e^{\mu (t-s)} + \sigma\int_s^t e^{\mu (t-v)} dW_v\\
&\sim N\Big(X_s e^{\mu (t-s)}, \, \sigma^2\int_s^t e^{2\mu (t-v)} dv \Big).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the reference. So, is there anyway I can simplify that last integral?

Comment: No, unless $\mu=0$. But from here, you can do many thing such as computing the mean and variance etc.

Comment: Gordon is obviously a whiz at this stuff ( thanks for great answer ) and I don't know of a better one but, to me, Oskendal is not a good recommedation for someone to get a handle on basic SDE. I've tried it. Maybe check out Evans's book.

Comment: @Gordon Okay, basically what you are saying is, if I want to simulate this process, I am going to need numerical methods.

Comment: @markleeds Thank you for the other reference. They both seem to have their strengths and weaknesses. Gordon's suggestion seems to talk about methods of solution, while Evan's seems to just give you the answer. Both are helpful.

Comment: Dear @the_src_dude . Gordon has an excellent reference. However I will recommend that you read chapter 4 and 5 in Arbitrage Theory in Continous Time by Björk because it collects all the relevant information in two chapters and you don't have to have a theoretical math background to understand. If you want to learn further, then you can move on to Oskendal

Comment: Yes, you need a certain numerical method.

Comment: @Gordon. Okay, I am looking at "An Algorithmic Introduction to Numerical Simulation of Stochastic Differential Equations" by Desmond J. Higham to try and figure that out next. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Sanjay Okay, I will see if my library has that book as well. I am not a finance person however, I just found an excellent application of SDEs in my engineering work and you quant guys seem to be the best at these things.

Comment: In the book(s) suggested in the answer and comments, you will see that the last integral: $\int_0^t e^{-\mu (s-t)} dWs$ is a random variable whose law is known to be gaussian with mean zero and variance $\int_0^t e^{-2\mu (s-t)} ds$. So you can simulate it for example.

Comment: Following up on Gordon’s answer, a closed form solution to the distribution of $X_t$ can be found by integrating the coefficient integral of the stochastic driver.

Comment: @Kermittfrog You mean it will be a distro of the form $\mathcal{N}(0,\int_{0}^{t} e^{-2 \mu (s-t)} ds)$ ?

Comment: @the_src_dude: please see the updates.

Comment: @Gordon Wow thank you!