# Deriving the variance of G2++ Model

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, variance, short-rate

**I'm studying G2++ Model in Brigo(2007)'s book.**

The model constructed as follows,

$$
r(t) = x(t) + y(t) + φ(t), \quad r(0) = r_0\\
$$
with the dynamics of $dx(t)$ and $dy(t)$ described by:
\begin{align}
dx(t) &= -ax(t)dt + σdW_1(t), \quad x(0) = 0,\\
dy(t) &= -by(t)dt + ηdW_2(t),\quad y(0) = 0,\\
\end{align}
and $dW_1(t)\cdot dW_2(t) = ρdt$.

**Problem:** When we calculate the variance, There is something that I cannot derive, which is described below:

$$∫^T_t(T-u)dx(u) = -a∫^T_t(T-u)x(u)du + σ∫^T_t(T-u)dW_1(u)$$
Then,
$$∫^T_t(T-u)x(u)du = x(t)∫^T_t(T-u)e^{-a(u-t)}du + σ∫^T_t(T-u)∫^T_te^{-a(u-s)}dW_1(s)du.$$

I tried to derive the above integral, $\int_t^T (T-u) x(u) \: du$, but failed.

**I want to know how to derive this equation.** Especially, where in the world $e^{-a(u-t)}$ and $σ∫^T_t(T-u)∫^T_te^{-a(u-s)}dW_1(s)du$ came from, from the above equation?

##### Below picture is just the raw source of my text:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It comes from a direct application of the solution to  $dx_t$

The solution for this SDE has already been [**derived by Gordon in this post**](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/49156/51407) where the only difference (*in your specified SDE*) is a sign-change in the drift-term. From the answer in the linked post, we observe that the solution to $dx_t$ in your case is given by:

$$
x_T = x_t e^{-a(T-t)} + \sigma\int_{t}^T  e^{-a(T-s)} \: dW_s.
$$

The derivations specified in Gordons answer involve the [**integrating factor method**](http://gormgeier.com/blog/2015/04/how-to-solve-stochastic-differential-equations-the-integrating-factor-technique/) which is also used to derive the solution for the well-known Vasicek one-factor short-rate model.

---

Let $0\leq t < u < T$. Now we can compute the integral in question:

\begin{align}
\int_t^T (T-u) \cdot x_u \: du &= \int_t^T (T-u)  \cdot \left[x_t e^{-a(u-t)} + \sigma\int_{t}^u  e^{-a(u-s)} \: dW_s \right] \: du \\
&=x_t \int_t^T (T-u) e^{-a(u-t)} \: du + \sigma\int_t^T (T-u)\int_{t}^u  e^{-a(u-s)} \: dW_s \: du.
\end{align}

In conclusion, $e^{-a(u-t)}$  and $\sigma\int_t^T (T-u)\int_{t}^u  e^{-a(u-s)} \: dW_s \: du$ comes from inserting the solution of $dx_t$ in the above integral. **I hope this provide some insight.**